# Examples of Stone algebras which are not Boolean algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

Grätzer, in his *Lattice Theory: Foundation*, describes a Stone algebra as a distributive lattice with pseudocomplementation $L$ which satisfies the Stone identity: for every $a \in L$, $\neg a \vee \neg\neg a = 1$, where "$\neg$" is the pseudocomplementation operation. Unfortunately, he doesn't delve too much into examples of this type of structure; specifically, I'm interested in examples of structures which are *not* Boolean algebras as well. I tried to find some topological examples, but couldn't come up with any (but then again, I know very little of topology). Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Natural examples of distributive lattices with pseudocomplementation come from lattices of open sets in topological spaces. Topologically, if $a$ is an open set, $\lnot a$ is the interior of the complement of $a$, and $\lnot\lnot a$ is the interior of the closure of $a$.

Now the Stone identity says that the space $X$ is the union of the sets $\lnot a$ and $\lnot\lnot a$. This means that $X$ is disconnected and $\lnot\lnot a$ is both open and closed, which happens if and only if $\lnot\lnot a = \text{cl}(a)$, i.e. the closure of $a$ is open. A space in which the closure of any open set is open is called an "extremally disconnected space". These are exactly the projective objects in the category of compact Hausdorff spaces.

---

**Edit:** You can find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698184/a-boolean-algebra-is-complete-if-its-stone-space-is-extremally-disconnected) that the Stone space of any complete Boolean algebra is extremally disconnected. So, for an explicit example, take $S(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$. The clopen sets form a Boolean algebra, but the lattice of open sets form a Stone algebra. As an example of an open set which is not clopen, take $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} [\{n\}]$, the set of all principal ultrafilters. Its closure is the whole space!

(**Edit 2:** Why? We want to show that the set of principal ultrafilters is dense in the Stone space $S(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$. A basic open set in the Stone space is $[A] = \{U\text{ an ultrafilter}\mid A\in U\}$ for $A\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. If $A = \emptyset$, then $[A]$ is empty, since no ultrafilter contains $\emptyset$. If not, pick $n\in A$. The principal ultrafilter $U_n$ generated by $n$ is $\{X\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\mid n\in X\}$. Since $n\in A$, $A\in U_n$, so $U_n\in [A]$.)

You ask about regular open sets in the comments. Note that in an extramlly disconnected space, an open set is regular if and only if it is clopen.

My favorite source for all these sorts of things is Johnstone's Stone Spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the very clear explanation. Do you know of any sources in which I can find more about extremally disconnected spaces? Presumably, it's not the case in such spaces that every open set is the interior of their own closure, right?

Comment: So, just to be clear, I'm trying to come up with an example of an extremally disconnected space which is not discrete and in which it's not the case that every open set is regular. I know that some Stone-Čech compactifications are extremally disconnected spaces, but I'm not sufficiently acquainted with them to obtain an example of an open set which is not regular.

Comment: Thanks, the edit was very useful. I'm going to check your references and see if I can work out the example.

Comment: By the way, what's the meaning of $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$?

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$, viewed as a (complete) Boolean algebra, and $S(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$ is its [Stone space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras).

Comment: Okay, so it's clear to me that, since $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite, there is at least one non-principal ultrafilter in $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$; hence, if the closure of the set of all principal ultrafilters is the whole space, then it's not the case that every open set in $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$ is regular. However, I can't quite see how to prove that the closure of the set of all principal ultrafilters is going to be the whole space. Can you give me some hints in that direction?

Comment: Show that the set of principal ultrafilters is dense: can you find one in any basic open set?

Comment: Well, the set of all principal ultrafilters is the basis for the topology, right? So if $A$ is an open set and $x \in A$, then there must be a principal ultrafilter $U$ such that $x \in U$ and $U \subseteq A$. Is that it?

Comment: Not quite. See my new edit.

Comment: Thanks. I mixed up the basis; one should set as a basis the set of all ultrafilters on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, not the set of all ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4):

I know you requested topological examples but here is another example of a Stone algebra that is not Boolean:

The chain $\mathbf{3}=\{0,e,1\}$ where $0<e<1$, $0=\neg e=\neg 1$, and $1=\neg 0$.

In some sense, this is the main example since every Stone algebra is isomorphic to a subalgebra of a direct product of $\mathbf{2}$'s and $\mathbf{3}$'s (where $\mathbf{2}$ is the 2-element Boolean algebra).

Comment: Ah, that's very nice! Do you have a reference for that fact? (I don't recall seeing it in Johnstone, but that doesn't mean it's not there...)

Comment: I read it in Cliff Bergman's universal algebra book.It's because $\mathbf{2}$ and $\mathbf{3}$ are the only subdirectly irreducible Stone algebras.

Comment: That's an interesting reference. I'll look it up!

Comment: @Nagase: proof (for the 2x3 result) is also given in Grätzer's *Lattice Theory: Foundation* book (has a section on Stone lattices). Further, note that in a Stone lattice the 2nd De Morgan law also holds (equivalently). In fact this may be a more motivating reason to introduce them, at least from a logic perspective.